# low sample size experimental design, t-test vs one way ANOVA

Tags: anova, t-test, experiment-design, statistical-power

I'm designing a biological experiment wherein the sample size is very limited, as each sample is very hard to get. Moreover, I need to have 4 independent groups, each receiving a different treatment.

I only really care about 2 comparisons: group  1 vs group 2, and g3 vs g4. My power analysis indicates my sample size is large enough to compare 1v2 with a t-test and 3v4 with a t-test. However, I worry that doing an ANOVA and post-hocs will lower the statistical power.

Question: If I know beforehand exactly what 2 groups I want to compare (and I don't care about the other comparisons), can I use t-tests instead of ANOVA?

Thanks!

Comment: If you happen to have a decent amount of pre-experimental information about the groups you are looking at, I'd suggest at least considering a Bayesian approach using informative priors.  I imagine you might not be familiar with this, so starting points would be the book *Regression and Other Stories* and the rstanarm R package. The book is available free as a PDF here: https://avehtari.github.io/ROS-Examples/

Answer (score 1):

If you reject the null hypothesis in the one-factor ANOVA, then you could do *ad hoc* comparisons of 1 vs 2 and 3 vs 4 using Tukey's HSD to avoid false discovery on multiple testing of the same data.
(I would not just use two 2-sample t tests.)

Without seeing your data, I can't predict whether those two HSD comparisons would lead to significant results.

HSD uses a somewhat different criterion than ANOVA, so there is no absolute *guarantee* any HSD comparisons will be significant. Try HSD and see what you find.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What I'm still wondering is with this design I'm not actually testing the same data twice, right? 1vs2 and 3 vs4, each group just used once? Am I not unnecessarily lowering power by correcting for multiple comparisons?

Comment: If you have no interest in comparisons other than 1 vs 2 and 3 vs 4, you could do just the two 2-sample t tests. // However, in a one-factor ANOVA, assuming all four groups to be equally variable, all of the data in all four groups are helping to estimate the common group variance. Then it would be possible (although maybe not likely) that the ANOVA would have better power than the t tests. // If this is for publication, a referee may insist on seeing the ANOVA.